# Calculate expected value given table of join pmf

Tags: probability

> **Problem 39.31.** The table below shows the joint probability function of a sailor's number of boating accidents $X$ and number of hospitalizations from these accidents $Y$ for this year.
>   \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
> Y\setminus X & 0     & 1     & 2     & 3 \\ \hline
> 0            & 0.70  & 0     & 0     & 0 \\ 
> 1            & 0.15  & 0.05  & 0     & 0 \\ 
> 2            & 0.06  & 0.02  & 0.01  & 0 \\ 
> 3            & 0.005 & 0.002 & 0.002 & 0.001
> \end{array}
>   Calculate the sailor's expected number of hospitalizations from boating accidents this year.

It seems like a simple problem, I think I am misunderstanding something? Aren't we simply calculating $\mathbb{E}[Y]$? I get .41

**Correct Answer is** $0.099$

Comment: How did you get $.41$?  That seems absurdly high, given the table.

Comment: To get $.099$ just do the sum mechanically.  $E[Y]=1\times (.05+.02+.002)+2\times (.01+.002)+3\times (.001)=.099$

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{P}[X = x] = \sum_{y}\mathbb{P}[X = x, Y = y]$ by the law of total probability. Use this result to get the answer

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the table. I assumed Y/X symbol meant Y along rows, X along columns. If so, $E[Y] = 1\times (0.15+0.05) + 2\times (0.06+0.02+0.01) + 3\times (0.005+0.002+0.002+0.001) = 0.41$?

Comment: @MinYoungKim That´s right.

Comment: @MinYoungKim I don´t know why the `correct answer` is $\mathbb E(Y)=0.099$. This is not correct.